# CSS Clearfix not clearing header

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my header elements interfering with my elements in my main page. The best way I can describe this issue is to show you so here is my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/n7530s2u/

```
<header class="cf">

    <div class="container cf">

        <div class="brand">

            <a href="#">Logo</a>

        </div>

        <ul class="main_nav cf">

            <li><a href="#">DISCOVER</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</header>

<div class="main cf">

    <div class="album_hero">

        <div class="album_hero_inner cf">

            <div class="album_cover"><img src="http://cdn.doandroidsdance.com/assets/2013/10/daft-ram-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="album_cover"><img src="http://cdn.doandroidsdance.com/assets/2013/10/daft-ram-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="album_cover"><img src="http://cdn.doandroidsdance.com/assets/2013/10/daft-ram-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="album_cover"><img src="http://cdn.doandroidsdance.com/assets/2013/10/daft-ram-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="album_cover"><img src="http://cdn.doandroidsdance.com/assets/2013/10/daft-ram-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="album_cover"><img src="http://cdn.doandroidsdance.com/assets/2013/10/daft-ram-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see the album covers seem to skip up until the header logo finishes. Also when removing the logo the main content seems to fix it self. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you and further questions are welcomed.

Comment: You have to clearfix the parent i.e. `.album_hero`: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/n7530s2u/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: inline-block; <-- add this
  vertical-align: middle; <-- add this
}
```

Comment: Then there is a slight margin below the header?

Comment: add this `vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by adding display: block; to the  in the header. It was pushing the height to 62px where the set height of the header was 60px.